# Show default linux printer?

Tags: linux

Linux command lpadmin will set the default printer. How does one show what the default printer is from the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get information about your current configuration use

```
$ lpoptions
```

The field your question is about is probably `printer-info`.

Btw, `lpq` prints the default printer, too.

```
$ lpq
Apple2 is ready
no entries
```

Comment: `lpoptions | grep -o 'printer-info[^ ]*'`

Comment: Wrong! The 'printer-info' field is just a comment, and it appears for every single printer (even if it's empty). Has nothing to do with default printer.

Answer (score 7):

`lpstat -d` shows you the default printer (if your system uses CUPS).

(Above advice is completely wrong. 'printer-info' has nothing to do with default or not default printer queue. It's just a field to hold a comment about the queue. Can contain *anything* you like...)

Answer (score 0):

This is not correct. lpq will show the printer queu and your place(your print jobs place), but lpstat will show the default printer